# How to set LUKS loading screen Debian

Tags: debian, luks

On linux mint and fedora, when you first boot a LUKS encrypted system, instead of a command line passphrase entering section, it has kind of a GUI that looks better than the default command line on Debian. I noticed that on Debian you can press escape and it will change to a similar type of menu. Is there any way to set this "GUI" type LUKS decryption screen as the default? Also what would be the proper terminology for this screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The proper terminology is "flicker-free boot",** it was implemented in Fedora about 2-3 years ago (here announcement on the hacker news - https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=18123984), so it's still relatively new, and many distributions are lacking proper support.

When it comes to Debian, I couldn't find much information like how it is supported. There are some forums topics/Reddit threads like this: https://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=30&t=148804 . This thread has some links that might help.

Finally, you might contact developers or fill a bug report about better support or request for documentation update/change.